# Query to calculate a percentage of a GEO surface in a radius

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I am GeoJSON unfortunately still a bloody beginner. Now I have to solve a problem and understand, unfortunately, no piece of systematics.

Can you please help me and explain how I can use MongoDB to evaluate GEO data for the following case.

We have three areas (for example, countries), these have a value (say base area) now I have a catchment area that covers all three countries in part. How do I get the percentage of each country?

Here is a graphic to visualize the problem:

*It is needed here e.g. the areas of A (n), B (n) and C (n).*
[image: visualization]

In the database (mongodb@3.2) I have corresponding document with GEO data. Example:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollecton",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
         "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": [
         [
           [
             13.6868862,
             51.063946
           ],
           [
             13.6873401,
             51.063999
           ],
           [
             13.6883277,
             51.0640888
           ],
             ...
           ]
         ]
     },
     "properties": {
        "name": "Land A",
        "qkm": 65.866862
     }
    },
  ]
}, ...
```